# Alert or confirm open 1 dialog box for some sites but about 10 in another site

Tags: javascript

I basically the following script with Greasemonkey on the latest Firefox:

```
let sites = ['google.com', 'mako.co.il'];

for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf(sites[i]) != -1 ) {

    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio')).forEach(function(audio) {
      audio.muted = true;
    });

    document.querySelector('*').style.display = 'none';

    if (confirm('Enough with this' + '' + sites[i] + '' + 'already!') === true) {
      txt = "You went out like a true hero!";
      document.location = 'https://google.com';
    } else {
      txt = "Please refresh this page and get out!";
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried using a nice `confirm()` box instead the alert.

---

The alert/confirm works only once in `google.com` (as well as other sites tested and omitted from the above code, which is the expected behavior), but in `mako.co.il` it works several times, in some kind of a wired loop.

Why would the alert/confirm appear about 10 times in mako.co.il before finalizing code execution?

Comment: I am unable to replicate, are you sure there isn't any other code running?

Comment: Hmm wired, there was indeed the extra code I just added in the edit, but even when I remove it the behavior is quite similar. I think I have this direction: The document.location is changed, later in the `confirm` from `mako.co.il` to `staicxxx.facebook.com` which seems to be some Facebook-oriented redirect being implemented `mako.co.il` but either way I cannot explain this.

Comment: @JoeLissner, did you check it with latest Greasemonkey? Did you had only 1 popup in `mako.co.il`? Thx!

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce. Can you verify that the script is only being loaded once?

Comment: It seems it does and that it comes from Greasemonkey (GM) --- To check that, I disabled the GM script and ran it manually. Then, it did run only once. So, the script itself seems to work fine.

Comment: Not the best fix, but you could create a global variable that your script checks, something like at the top of it do `var scriptHasRun = false;` then wrap the rest of it in `if(!scriptHasRun) { ... }` with the first line in that if statement being `scriptHasRun = true`